# Passing multiple objects using RedirectToAction() in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This works:

```
 return RedirectToAction("Someplace", object1);
```

But when I do this:

```
return View("Someplace", new { object1 = Object1, object2 = Object2 });
```

One of the objects gets dropped.

Already tried wrapping it into a new class and it didn't work, either.

Don't want to use session variables or TempData

Comment: You don't really want to have an anonymous type as your model. Create a View Model that encapsulates your 2 models as properties.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! didn't think it would take a new view just to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already tried something that looked like this and object2 was null in your view??

```
var vm = new YourViewModel();
vm.FirstObject = Object1;
vm.TheNextObject = Object2;
return View("Someplace", vm);
```

Comment: I tried it with a new class, but not a new viewmodel. Did the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to create a new class, referred to as a ViewModel. So Something like this:

```
public class SomeplaceViewModel()
{
    public object Object1 {get;set;}
    public object Object2 {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
var viewModel = new SomeplaceViewModel()
{
     Object1 = object1,
     Object2 = object2
};
return View("Someplace", viewModel);
```

And finally, in your view you can use the model by inserting this at the top of the view file:

```
@model SomeplaceViewModel
```